# emberjs 1.0pre examples

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

and thank you ahead of time. I have recently changed the emberjs dependency in my application to 1.0.0pre, and am having trouble with views rendering. I tried downloading from [emberjs/examples](https://github.com/emberjs/examples) on github seeing as how the latest commit was for switching to 1.0.0pre.

When I tried opening the applications, I noticed handlebars wasn't referenced, but after fixing that all the applications have the same problem I had: Rendering Views yielded empty containers and the console was silent (on my application even the console.trace() int he development build of ember didn't help while the rest of the console was silent).

I was wondering if anyone knows any working examples I could look at for ArrayControllers and/or CollectionViews on ember 1.0 pre so that I could use that as reference.

> I don't have enough reputation to vote up on answers, but thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: I found ember-tunes, and it is looking great. https://github.com/elucid/ember-tunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Handlebars action helper works in EmberJS 0.9.8.1, but not Ember 1.0 Pre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492003/handlebars-action-helper-works-in-emberjs-0-9-8-1-but-not-ember-1-0-pre)
Make sure you have the absolute latest handlebars from https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/downloads