# Handlebars action helper works in EmberJS 0.9.8.1, but not Ember 1.0 Pre

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

See http://jsfiddle.net/gazmcghee/v6PSA/. Clicking the link shows an alert. But changing the version of EmberJS under "Manage Resources" to https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-1.0.pre.js causes the link to disappear. How do I fix this ?

Comment: This is a good question, but for a question like this, with relatively little code involved, it's helpful to include code in the question instead of just a link to jsFiddle (so the question remains useful if jsFiddle goes down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the EmberJS version 0.9.8.1, Handlebars was included by default in Ember.

Its not the case with the 1.0pre version, so you have to manually add it.

PS: Don't forget to add `Add.initialize()`, or you will see unexpected behaviour.

[Here is your JSFiddle that includes Handlebars](http://jsfiddle.net/HRweY/).

Comment: Thankyou very much for this. I began with another working fiddle, which was why I was using the older version. In my project I'm using 1.0pre with handlebars.runtime-1.0.0.beta.6, and that also doesn't work, but the slightly more recent version of handlebars you suggest, [1.0.rc.1](https://github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js) fixes it. How would/should I have known about this? The Starter Kit from emberjs.com doesn't have this latest handlebars. Is  there a blog I should tune into?